# attr id inside a cloned div

Tags: jquery, html

i have an entire div with a checkbox inside, that has the class of .sv and id of #sv1
I want this checkbox to have an unique Id everytime the entire div is cloned
Therefore i want it to increment by 1 for each time the clone function is fired. eg. sv1 sv2 sv3 . . .

this is what i have so far:

```
$("#btnid").click(function () {
    $('.valgmulighed:last').clone().attr('id', 'valgmulighed' + ($('.valgmulighed').length + 1)).insertAfter('.valgmulighed:last');
    $('.sv:last').attr("id", "sv" + (index + 1));
});
```

ignore "`valgmulighed`" this is just for the entire div.

Comment: That looks fine. So what's the issue now? What's your question?

Comment: `index` is not defined, did you see that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is the following. The `index` is not at all defined. So you need to use the length as the `id` replacing stuff.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#btnid").click(function () {
    $('.valgmulighed:last').clone().attr('id', 'valgmulighed' + ($('.valgmulighed').length + 1)).insertAfter('.valgmulighed:last');
    $('.sv:last').attr("id", "sv" + ($('.sv').length));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<button id="btnid">Click</button>
<div class="valgmulighed" id="valgmulighed1">
  Hi
  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="sv1" class="sv" />
</div>
```

Inspect and see the `id` for both `checkbox` as well as `div`.

Comment: thats pretty cool mate. Thank you! 
- so by adding ($('.sv').length) you are using a non unique identifier to do the count? couldnt i use index in this case as well?

Comment: @JeppeC there's no `index`!